# MYSQL select id that is involved in all projects

Tags: mysql

I have table name 'workOnlist'

columns are
    ID , projectNum

```
values are
1  , 1229
2  , 1229
3  , 3370
2  , 3370
1  , 4400
2  , 4400
3  , 4400
```

how to show ID which involved in all project(1129,3370,4400)

select ID from workOnlist Where(id that finished all 1129, 3370, 4400)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know the number of projects then you can use this:

```
select ID from workonlist
group by id
having count(distinct(projectNum))=3;
```

Or you can use this:

```
select ID from workonlist
group by id
having count(distinct(projectNum))=
            (select count(distinct(projectNum)) from workonlist);
```

[fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/30ade/7)

Comment: it works! do you know how to get the number of projects

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select ID from workOnlist Where id IN(1129, 3370, 4400)
```